# How do I skip a newly created folder while looping through sub folders?

Tags: excel, vba

I've cobbled together lots of code from various previous posts (thanks to all of you!) and I almost have a working solution.
What I would like to happen is:

- user chooses a folder
- a new folder is created inside that folder and some .dwg files moved to it
- the code then drills down to the next folder and does the same.

My problem is that the code is drilling down into the newly created folder and creating and endless cycle. Is there a way to skip the folder that i have just created? The folder is always named "Original DWGs DD-mm-yy" so I was thinking about adding

```
If InStr(FromPath, "original") = 0 Then
Exit Sub
End If
```

But I don't think "exit sub" is the right thing to do inside the fso loop?

```
Option Explicit
Dim sFolder As String

Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    ' Open the select folder prompt
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
            sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    If sFolder <> "" Then ' if a file was chosen
   Debug.Print sFolder
    End If

DrillDown

End Sub

Sub DrillDown()
    Dim FSO As Object 'FileSystemObject
    Dim fldStart As Object 'Folder
    Dim fld As Object 'Folder
    Dim fl As Object 'File
    Dim Mask As String

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject") ' late binding

    Set fldStart = FSO.GetFolder(sFolder) ' <-- use your FileDialog code here

    Mask = "*.dwg"
       For Each fld In fldStart.SubFolders
        ListFolders fld, Mask
    Next
End Sub


Sub ListFolders(fldStart As Object, Mask As String)
    Dim fld As Object 'Folder
    Dim FromPath As String

    For Each fld In fldStart.SubFolders
        Debug.Print fld.Path & "\"

'move all specified files from FromPath to ToPath.
'Note: It will create the folder ToPath for you
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim FileExt As String
    Dim FNames As String
    Dim diaFolder As FileDialog
    Dim selected As Boolean
    Dim FldCheck As String

    FromPath = fld.Path & "\"

    ToPath = FromPath & "Original DWGs " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yy")  '<< Change only the destination folder

Debug.Print ToPath

    FileExt = "*.dwg"   '<< Change

    If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FromPath = FromPath & "\"
    End If

    FNames = Dir(FromPath & FileExt)
    If Len(FNames) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No .dwg files in " & FromPath
       'Exit Sub
       GoTo Err
         End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")


If FSO.FolderExists(ToPath) = False Then
        FSO.CreateFolder (ToPath)
End If

    FSO.MoveFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath

Err:
    FileExt = "*.err"   '<< Change

    If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FromPath = FromPath & "\"
    End If

    FNames = Dir(FromPath & FileExt)
    If Len(FNames) = 0 Then
        'MsgBox "No .err files in " & FromPath
        'Exit Sub
        GoTo Bak
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If FSO.FolderExists(ToPath) = False Then
   FSO.CreateFolder (ToPath)
End If

    FSO.MoveFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath


    '---
Bak:
    FileExt = "*.bak"   '<< Change

    If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FromPath = FromPath & "\"
    End If

    FNames = Dir(FromPath & FileExt)
    If Len(FNames) = 0 Then
        'MsgBox "No .bak files in " & FromPath
        'Exit Sub
        GoTo Log
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If FSO.FolderExists(ToPath) = False Then
   FSO.CreateFolder (ToPath)
End If

    FSO.MoveFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath

    '---
Log:
    FileExt = "*.log"   '<< Change

    If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FromPath = FromPath & "\"
    End If

    FNames = Dir(FromPath & FileExt)
    If Len(FNames) = 0 Then
        'MsgBox "No .log files in " & FromPath
        Exit Sub
        End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If FSO.FolderExists(ToPath) = False Then
   FSO.CreateFolder (ToPath)
End If

    FSO.MoveFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath

    Set diaFolder = Nothing

        ListFolders fld, Mask
    Next

End Sub
```

I've added the code as suggested. However now it loops through and creates 6 "original DWG" each inside the previous one, and moves the files into the 5th level. Then I get a path not found error?

File path after the code has run:
C:\Users\d.holpin\Desktop\Matts Data\New folder\E2000 Circuit Drawings\85100004 ELECTRICAL CIRCUIT**ARCHIVE**\Original DWGs 23-09-19\Original DWGs 23-09-19\Original DWGs 23-09-19\Original DWGs 23-09-19**Original DWGs 23-09-19**\Original DWGs 23-09-19

Files have been moved from Archive to the second to last Original DWGs (highlighted in bold)

Code as it stands is:

```
Option Explicit
Dim sFolder As String

Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    ' Open the select folder prompt
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
            sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    If sFolder <> "" Then ' if a file was chosen
   Debug.Print sFolder
    End If

DrillDown

End Sub

Sub DrillDown()
    Dim FSO As Object 'FileSystemObject
    Dim fldStart As Object 'Folder
    Dim fld As Object 'Folder
    Dim fl As Object 'File
    Dim Mask As String
    Dim test As String

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject") ' late binding

    Set fldStart = FSO.GetFolder(sFolder) ' <-- use your FileDialog code here

    Mask = "*.dwg"

    For Each fld In fldStart.SubFolders
    test = InStr(1, fld.Name, "Original DWGs ")
    Debug.Print test
    If InStr(1, fld.Name, "Original DWGs ") = 0 Then ListFolders fld, Mask

    Next

       'For Each fld In fldStart.SubFolders
        'ListFolders fld, Mask
    'Next
End Sub


Sub ListFolders(fldStart As Object, Mask As String)
    Dim fld As Object 'Folder
    Dim FromPath As String

    For Each fld In fldStart.SubFolders '2nd tme around it jump from here to the end if listfolders?

     Debug.Print fld.Path & "\"

'move all specified files from FromPath to ToPath.
'Note: It will create the folder ToPath for you
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim FileExt As String
    Dim FNames As String
    Dim diaFolder As FileDialog
    Dim selected As Boolean
    Dim FldCheck As String
FromPath = ""
    FromPath = fld.Path & "\"

    ToPath = FromPath & "Original DWGs " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yy")  '<< Change only the destination folder

Debug.Print ToPath

    FileExt = "*.dwg"   '<< Change

    If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FromPath = FromPath & "\"
    End If

    FNames = Dir(FromPath & FileExt)
    If Len(FNames) = 0 Then
        'MsgBox "No .dwg files in " & FromPath
       'Exit Sub
       GoTo Err
         End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")


If FSO.FolderExists(ToPath) = False Then
        FSO.CreateFolder (ToPath)
End If

    FSO.MoveFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath

Err:
    FileExt = "*.err"   '<< Change

    If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FromPath = FromPath & "\"
    End If

    FNames = Dir(FromPath & FileExt)
    If Len(FNames) = 0 Then
        'MsgBox "No .err files in " & FromPath
        'Exit Sub
        GoTo Bak
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If FSO.FolderExists(ToPath) = False Then
   FSO.CreateFolder (ToPath)
End If

    FSO.MoveFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath


    '---
Bak:
    FileExt = "*.bak"   '<< Change

    If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FromPath = FromPath & "\"
    End If

    FNames = Dir(FromPath & FileExt)
    If Len(FNames) = 0 Then
        'MsgBox "No .bak files in " & FromPath
        'Exit Sub
        GoTo Log
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If FSO.FolderExists(ToPath) = False Then
   FSO.CreateFolder (ToPath)
End If

    FSO.MoveFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath

    '---
Log:
    FileExt = "*.log"   '<< Change

    If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FromPath = FromPath & "\"
    End If

    FNames = Dir(FromPath & FileExt)
    If Len(FNames) = 0 Then
        'MsgBox "No .log files in " & FromPath
        'Exit Sub
        GoTo FIN
        End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If FSO.FolderExists(ToPath) = False Then
   FSO.CreateFolder (ToPath)
End If

    FSO.MoveFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath
FIN:
    Set diaFolder = Nothing
    FromPath = ""

    ToPath = ""

        ListFolders fld, Mask
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In DrillDown you should add the check you mentioned where you loop through the SubFolders:

```
For Each fld In fldStart.SubFolders
    If InStr(1, fld.Name, "Original DWGs ") = 0 Then ListFolders fld, Mask
Next
```